# Adding data using codeigniter and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am new in codeigniter I want to retrieve data into table using ajax 
but no result found please help me to solve my problem

**this is controller code**

```
public function indexajax()
      {


          $this->load->model("usersmodel");
         $data['pagetitle']=" -->All Users Using Ajax<--";



         $this->load->view("template/admin/header");
          $this->load->view("users/allusersusingajax");

          $this->load->view("template/admin/footer");

      }
      public function get_all_users()
      {
         if($this->input->post("action")=='FetchAllUserUingAjax1'){

              $this->load->model("usersmodel");
             // print_r($this->input->post("action"));
              echo ($this->input->post("action"));
              $data["allu"]=$this->usersmodel->ShowAllUsers("users");
 foreach ($allu as $a):
        echo'<tr>
            <td>'.$a->id.'</td>
            <td>'.$a->username.'</td>
           <td><button class="deletenew" id="'.$a->id.'">deletenew</button></td>

        </tr>';
        endforeach;



          }




      }


}
```

**this is my model code**

```
public function ShowAllUsers()
        {
            //$this->db->order_by("id", "desc");
        //  $this->db->limit(20);
            $sql=$this->db->get("users");
            return $sql->result();

        }
```

This is my view code

**this is my HTML**

```
<div class="userdataajax table-responsive">
    <table class=" table table-responsive table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>image</th>
            <th> full name</th>
            <th>email</th>
            <th>usertype</th>
            <th>status</th>
            <th>reg date</th>
            <th>reg time</th>
            <th>delete</th>
            <th>edit</th>
            <th>Activate</th>
            <th>disactivate</th>

        </tr>


    </table>
</div>
```

**this is my ajax calling trying to  retrieve and delete data**

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        FetchAllUserUingAjax();

        function FetchAllUserUingAjax() {

            $.ajax({
                url:'<?php echo base_url()?>Users/get_all_users',
                method:"post",

                success:function (data) {
                    $(".userdataajax table").append(data);

                }
            })
            var action="FetchAllUserUingAjax1";
            $.ajax({
                url:"<?php echo base_url()?>Users/get_all_users",
                method:"post",
                data:{action:action},
                success:function (data) {
                    $(".userdataajax table tr ").not("table tr:first").remove();
                    $(".userdataajax table").append(data);
                    Table();


                }
            })

        }
/******************/
        $(".deletenew").on("click",function () {
            var id=$(this).attr('id');
            $.ajax({
                url:'<?php echo base_url()?>Users/deleteusers',
                method:"post",
                data:{id:id},
                success:function () {
                    FetchAllUserUingAjax();

                }

            })
        })

    })

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
                 public function get_all_users()
                      {
                         if($this->input->post("action")=='FetchAllUserUingAjax1'){

                              $this->load->model("usersmodel");
                             // print_r($this->input->post("action"));
                              echo ($this->input->post("action"));
                              $data["allu"]=$this->usersmodel->ShowAllUsers("users");
                               $this->load->view("template/admin/header");
                              //make another view show_users,make a button in page
                            //alluersusing ajax give that button id 'but'
                          $this->load->view("users/show_users,$data");

                          $this->load->view("template/admin/footer");
                }
            <script>
             $("#but").click(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "<?php echo base_url()?>Users/get_all_users",
                        success: function(data) {
                            $("#get").html(data);
                            //console.log(data);
                        }
                    });
                });

            </script>

        //add below code to 'show_users' page or view
       <?php foreach ($allu as $a):
                echo'<tr>
                    <td>'.$a->id.'</td>
                    <td>'.$a->username.'</td>
                   <td><button class="deletenew" id="'.$a->id.'">deletenew</button></td>

                </tr>';
                endforeach;

//hope this will help
```

Comment: You Welcome :-)